# How do I find the .data() (jQuery) equivalent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
 var info = $($(r).find(".BuyPriceBox")).find(".PurchaseButton").data();
```

r is a html page returned from an ajax GET call, which contains a button which I am trying to get the data from

which I am trying to change into the JavaScript equivalent

I can't find anything that would resemble ".data()" in JavaScript?
Could anyone help me with this, and if kind enough help me translate it to JavaScript?

Comment: It is `.dataset` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: @itsgoingdown hmm, so how would I translate it into javascript wholly?

Comment: Have you tried reading the jQuery code to see how jQuery does it? JQuery is "just" JavaScript code that somebody else has written for you, so it's not a question of *translating* it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a fake `get` call:

```
function getData(cb) {
  var html = [
    '<div><div class="BuyPriceBox">',
    '<button class="PurchaseButton" data-id="one">Click</button>',
    '</div></div>'
  ].join('');
  setTimeout(cb, 1000, html);
}

getData(function(html) {

  // create a new element and attach the html received
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = html;

  // Then use `querySelector` to grab the element
  // and get the dataset (an object)
  var button = temp.querySelector('.BuyPriceBox .PurchaseButton');
  var id = button.dataset.id; // one

});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/exfvn2zx/5/)